# Angular Js Animate function in custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Here is the application code:

```
(function(){

  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

  myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'about.html'
      })
      .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'contact.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
  })

  myApp.directive('menuRight', function(){

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'menu.html',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var mB = document.getElementsByClassName('menuBtn');
        var m = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
        var menu = angular.element(m);
        var menuButton = angular.element(mB);

        menu.css({
          "left": -100 + "px"
        });

        menuButton.click(function(){
            if(menu.hasClass('visible')) {
                menu.animate({'left': -100 + 'px'}, 200).removeClass('visible');
            } else {
                menu.animate({'left': 0}, 400).addClass('visible');
            }
        });
      }
    }

  })

})()
```

The index file has three tags:

```
<div ng-view></div>
<button class="menuBtn">Toggle Menu</button><br><br>
<menu-right></menu-right>
```

**This code is working fine.** 
**Running Plunker link:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7VO0RZstMBwQzH613an?p=preview

This code is doing two things.
1. Loading a custom directive which is displaying the menu.
2. Routing to 3 pages home, about, contact through that directive.

Now above the custom directive there is a Toggle button that is sliding the menu from left. That is done through link function **using jquery**.

This directive is **using jquery** to do **slide effect**.

**Now my Question is:**
I would like to improve this code. Using angular Animate.
Or using controller in directive.

There is an **active class** applied to first li inside the menu template. But when I click on other li tags from menu I need to change the active class from/to the clicked li.

Looking for some great answers from great community.
Thanks...